# Наскільки типовою є конструкції виду "що ним/нею/ними" замість "яким/якою/якими"?

Tags: синтаксис

Іноді бачу в деяких текстах, що замість займенників *яким/якою/якими* використовуються конструкції виду *"що ним/нею/ними"*. Наприклад:

> "...портрети й малюнки, що ними Ганнуся наївно обліпила стіни, силкуючись надати хоч якоїсь затишності голій кімнаті" (В. Підмогильний, Місто).

Підкажіть, будь ласка: Це повністю синонімічні конструкції, чи вони мають різні відтінки значення/особливості вживання? Вони є застарілими, чи їх можна використовувати й зараз? Наскільки вони типові в стандартній літературній українській мові?

Comment: Переважно взаємозамінні

Comment: Дещо схоже запитання: [«Що в нього, що з ним, що про нього тощо»](/q/7138).

Answer (score -1):

Є дуже кльовий сервіс, котрий дозволяє шукати приклади вжитку слів та виразів в українському корпусі Грак. [Тут, на приклад, перелічені всі вживання виразу "що нею" у корпусі](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac15&tab=advanced&keyword=%D1%89%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8E&attrs=word%2Clemma&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=s%2Cg&refs=%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.mediaName%2C%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.locCode&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1&f_tab=advanced&c_itemsPerPage=500&c_customrange=1&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22iquery%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%D1%89%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8E%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22iqueryrow%22%2C%22iquery%22%3A%22%D1%89%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8E%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A5846%7D%5D). Сервіс дозволяє налаштовувати запити так, щоб фільтрувати окремі частини мови, шукати за леммою, а не за конкретним відмінком/формою слова,  і так далі. Хоча, й такий простий запит показує, що така конструкція часто вживалася в укаїнській літературі.

Хоча, на саме питання повністю відповісти не можу (чи це діалектизм, чи вживання дещо інше від ", якою", і т.д.).

Comment: Можливо ви могли б якось обрибити результати за цим посиланням. Наприклад, вказати в які саме роки воно зустрічається вперше, ще краще - завантажити дані звідти і побудувати графік по роках. Можливо можна щось цікаве зробити з авторами тощо.